# Microsoft Security Essentials Not Monitoring

Tags: anti-virus, ms-security-essentials

When I boot into Windows Vista, Microsoft Security Essentials is set to run when the system starts. When I open the program, it says `Microsoft Security Essentials isn't monitoring your computer because the program's service stopped.` It tells me that it can't update definitions or enable real time protection unless I do it manually (every time I boot). Is there a way I can fix this so I always have real time protection and updating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go in to computer management, (Click the `Start Orb` > Right click on `Computer` > Click on `Manage`)

Next, go down to `Services and Applications` > `Services` and look for `Microsoft Antimalware Service`

Make sure that this is set to `Automatic`.

[image]

If this is already set to `Automatic`, it is possible that you are simply not giving it enough time to fully start. I have seen some older machines, or even newish ones that simply have so many items set to start with the machine, it can take a good couple of minutes for the Antivirus service to start.

Comment: @Nironan12 - What method worked, was it due to not giving it time or was the service not set to automatic?

Comment: The service wasn't set to automatic, it was on manual.

Comment: @Nironan12 Cool, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In Winows XP:

1. Open the *Start* menu
2. Select *Run*
3. Execute `services.msc`
4. Make sure that the *Microsoft AntiMalware Service* is running, start it if it is not

Comment: What about the service?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to deal with this very problem after installing [Wise Care 365](http://www.wisecleaner.com/wisecare365.html) and following all its suggestions for optimising my XP Pro system (recently reinstalled, and laboriously shoved though Windows Update).

I'm not sure exactly what I changed (almost certainly something in the *WiseCare StartUpServices* facility), but the net result was Microsoft Security Essentials wasn't working *"because the app's service stopped"*, and clicking on the rather promising *Start now* button didn't apparently do anything.

After calling on my Google-fu, I ended up in *Administrative Tools - > Services*, where I ***restarted*** the *Microsoft Antimalware* service. Bingo! - Security Essentials icon immediately changed from red to green!

All was not sweetness and light though, since I had to restart the service every time the machine booted up. After further investigation I discovered that the *Microsoft Antimalware* service depends on ***Remote Procedure Call (RPC)***, which was set to StartUp type ***Manual***. I don't really understand things at this level - but I'd just made a complete [Paragon system backup](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/br-free/) anyway, so I changed it to ***Automatic***. And for good measure I changed *Antimalware - > Recovery -> Subsequent failures* to ***Restart the service***.

Everything works just dandy now, whether I understand it or not. A full reinstall is always daunting, but it got my house PC boot time down from 4 minutes to less than 1, so it'll be well worth the time spent.